# Parse header information

Tags: php, array, parsing

**Concrete Context:** I parse the header information from curl execution/request and get the array named `$headerARR`. At this point it looks like the next example, but it can vary and the content-type can be on any index (not have a certain order). I need to work around this, because it is the format accepted by the software engine and I not have the authority to change it:

```
array (
  0 => 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
  1 => 'Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 19:32:37 GMT',
  2 => 'Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.2.15',
  3 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.15',
  4 => 'Set-Cookie: Avisistema=ihk9t1ms6r8i0u1j5t6jpjrqei; path=/; HttpOnly',
  5 => 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
  6 => 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
  7 => 'Pragma: no-cache',
  8 => 'Set-Cookie: Avisistema=ihk9t1ms6r8i0u1j5t6jpjrqei; expires=Tue, 18-Jun-2019 03:32:37 GMT; Max-Age=28799; path=/; HttpOnly',
  9 => 'Set-Cookie: SageFirmeware=Avisistema.A.0.2015.01.10; expires=Tue, 18-Jun-2019 03:32:37 GMT; Max-Age=28799; path=/; HttpOnly',
  10 => 'Content-Length: 232',
  11 => 'Content-Type: application/json',
)
```

I determine wich `Content-Type` I use with this code:

```
    //array construct:
    $ch = curl_init();
    $Data      = curl_exec($ch);
    $Body      = substr($Data, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    $headers   = $Data;
    $headerARR = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, substr($headers, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE))));
    //can update anything after this line....
    $head      = '';
    foreach ($headerARR as $line) {
        $leed = explode(':', $line);
        if (strpos($leed[0], "Content-Type") !== false) {
            $head = str_replace(' ', '', $leed[1]);
        }
    }
```

**Is there any shorter alternative?**

**Is there any way to get better performance?**

**I can not change before or during the generation of the array, since the content-type is wanted to carry a separate function in the future.**

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where do `$Data` and `$ch` come from? Otherwise all we can work with is the array search, and that's not much. Also: Shorter code is not always faster or better code, so shortness shouldn't be your main goal. One example: Once you've found the header you could `break` out of the loop. That would make your code faster/better, but also longer.

Comment: `$Data` and `$ch` come from the execution of the curls

Comment: Show us the `$Data` string and we might be able to show you a more direct approach.

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not know what string string you are talking about, I show you the array that is what you should use to search for the text, I do not know if you understand the approach or you want to do something else that I have not indicated what I should do ...

Comment: I am assuming that you have posted `$headerARR`. KIKO was saying that we can explain a very basic technique and show you how to perform an early `break` in a loop, or you can provide the raw input before you chop and filter it.  With the raw `$Data` string we may be able to show you a more direct solution.

Comment: this assignment is pointless and just adds confusion and bloat to your code `$headers   = $Data;` --- if you just need the content type, maybe a regex will work, something like this `preg_match("/Content-Type: (?P<content_type>[^\n]+)/", substr($Data, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)), $match)` instead of exploding and iteration.  [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/uGqjeY/1)

Comment: That's kind of what I was going to suggest (not that exact pattern), but we aren't meant to post answers as  comments.  @Artistic https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329

Comment: @walternuñez Your question will probably qualify for reopening if you simply include "concrete context" by providing the input string.

Comment: @mickmackusa i dont have a the string; i have and array. can you view the array `$headerARR`

Comment: @mickmackusa Check Again..

Comment: That edit will not get your question reopened.  Why are you been resistant? I don't understand your motivation.  My answer shows that splitting the `$Data` on the end of line characters is unnecessary work.  I cannot vote to reopen until you have posted the `$Data` string.

Comment: @mickmackusa ok

Answer (score 3):

You can directly isolate and extract the content type by matching the start of the line, the label and a space, then restart the fullstring match, then match one or more non-newline characters.

Pattern Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QZz9IE/1/

PHP: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jZsFd))

```
echo preg_match('~^Content-Type: \K.+~m', $Data, $match) ? $match[0] : 'fail';
```

Output:

```
application/json
```

Comment: We should refrain from answering clearly off-topic questions.

Comment: @dfhwze why the question is off-topic ??

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for the answer i tha i look.

Comment: @dfhwze I agree that the OP should have provided a more complete question.  I felt that my hand was forced after Artistic's commented solution.  Question resolving comments lead to page abandonment.  I would not have answered if I could have deleted Artistic's comment.   I will not be offended if diamond mods want to scrub this page.

Comment: @mickmackusa I get your point. Let's wait and see how the community handles this one :)

Comment: @walter , KIKO and I were very clear about wanting to see the `$Data` string and why it was important to providing the most direct solution (and highest quality review).  I was going to withhold my answer until the question was complete, but when a suboptimal (IMO) solution was provided there would be little motivation for you to give your question any more attention.  Because I didn't want future researchers to copy-paste the commented solution, I posted what I felt was best after fabricating some semblence of your input.  You should complete your question with the required ingredient.

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not have a text string; I have an array with which you must work. I'm not going to give you something that is not inside the data or the structure presented. it's as if someone tells you how to sumo numbers and you answer does not want number give me letters ...

Comment: In your posted code, `$Data` is immediately processed by `substr()`.  This means you have a string or your code does not work because `substr()` ONLY works on a string.  I don't how to explain it any clearer.  https://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php  We would like you to post your string before you `explode()` it.